# Laravel - How to subtract the counts of two fields

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application I have this query in the Controller:

```php
$school = Auth::user()->school_id;
$registrationTypeName = "Core";

$studentRegistrations = DB::table('my_classess AS c')
   ->leftJoin('students AS ch', function($join) use ($school)
   {
   $join->on('ch.id', '=', 'c.class_head_id')
   ->where('ch.school_id', '=', $school);
   })
   ->leftJoin('students AS s', function($join) use ($student)
   {
   $join->on('c.id', '=', 's.class_id')
   ->where('s.school_id', '=', $school);
   })
   ->leftJoin('registrations AS r', function($join) use ($school)
   {
   $join->on('s.id', '=', 'r.student_id')
   ->where('r.company_id', '=', $school)
   ->where('r.is_registered', '1');
   })
   ->join('registration_types AS rt', function($join) use ($school, $registrationTypeName)
   {
   $join->on('r.registration_type_id', '=', 'rt.id')
   ->where('rt.school_id', '=', $school)
   ->where('rt.registration_type', 'LIKE', '%'.$registrationTypeName.'%');
    })
    ->where('c.school_id', '=', $school)
    ->select(
             'c.class_name',
              DB::raw('COALESCE(CONCAT(ch.first_name, " ", ch.last_name), "None") AS class_head'),
              DB::raw('COALESCE(COUNT(r.id), "0") AS total_registered'),
              DB::raw('COALESCE(COUNT(s.id), "0") AS total_students'),
            )
            ->groupby('c.id')
            ->get();
```

The above code is working fine.

But from the same query, I want to get another column called total_unregistered by subtracting total_registered from total_student as:

total_unregistered = total_student - total_registered

I did this:

```
DB::raw('SUM(total_student - total_registered) as total_unregistered'),
```

but got the error:

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_student'

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: My advice is to break this query up into smaller pieces as it is already doing too much. Also, this query probably shoudn't be in the controller - retrieving data like this should be done elsewhere, like in a service or repository class. The role of a controller is normally just to validate a request and then forward it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use alias columns in select statements ....

you should recalculate it:

```
->select(
             'c.class_name',
              DB::raw('COALESCE(CONCAT(ch.first_name, " ", ch.last_name), "None") AS class_head'),
              DB::raw('COALESCE(COUNT(r.id), "0") AS total_registered'),
              DB::raw('COALESCE(COUNT(s.id), "0") AS total_students'),
              DB::raw('(COALESCE(COUNT(s.id), 0)-COALESCE(COUNT(r.id), 0)) as total_unregistered ')
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_student'
```

You use a column "total_student" in your calculation, but the correct alias of the column is "total_students", ending with "s"